# Div-container is moving while resizing the browser window

Tags: html, css

Detailed description:

I have two containers which both held 50% of the max browser window. They are side by side. In these containers are two futher containers which are designed like a button.

Like this:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnIVf.png)

Now my problem is when i resize my browser from left to right the divs are moving away but i want them to stay where they are.

Here is some code for Div1 and div2:

```
<div id='picturediv1' class="image">
<div class="ghost">  
<a id="LK2" target="_blank" href="hehehe">Some link here</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Here some code for Div3 and Div4:

```
<div id='picturediv2' class="image2">
<div class="ghost2">
<a id="LK2" class="TFG2"  target="_blank" href="some link here" style="color:black;">Test2</a>
</div>
</div>
```

And some CSS code for div 2 and 4. I Only post for div2 cause they are both most identical.

CSS for div2:

```
      .ghost
            {
                /* position centered */
                display:inline-block;
                position: absolute;
                margin-top:20%;
                margin-left:50%;
                -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
                -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
                transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
                /* text styles */
                font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;
                font-size: 13pt;
                letter-spacing: 0.3em;
                color:#ffffff;
                /* modify text */
                text-decoration:none;
                text-transform:uppercase;
                text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;
                /* add a border */
                border:0.15em solid #fff;
                padding:0.4em 0.6em;
                /* animate the change */
                -webkit-transition: color 300ms, background 500ms, border-color 700ms;
                transition: color 300ms, background 500ms, border-color 700ms;
                text-align: center;
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                font-weight: 900;
                line-height: 60px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                width:50%;
                text-align:center;  
            }
```

I added a few comments for a better understanding i hope i descriped it good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of flexbox to achieve the desired output like this.

You can make use of `flex-direction:(row/column)` depending on the how you want the sub elements to align as demonstrated on the div1 and div2 to vertically align the text Div1 and the sub div 3.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  /*Generates a flexbox layout with default flex direction as row */
  width: 100%;
  /* Not really required */
  align-items: center;
  /*Aligns contents vertically */
  justify-content: center;
  /*Aligns contents horizontally */
  text-align: center;
  /*Aligns further text in the center */
}

#div1,
#div2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items: center;
  /*Aligns contents vertically */
  justify-content: center;
  /*Aligns contents horizontally */
  text-align: center;
  /*Aligns further text in the center */
}

#div3,
#div4 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div id="div1">
    Div 1
    <div id="div3">Div 3</div>
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    Div 2
    <div id="div4">Div 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```